# Can't find Brew installed packages on Mac M1 in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, homebrew, apple-m1

I'm having trouble installing packages and using them in Pycharm. I've followed various threads (I'm new to Macs and seem to have tried everything) now I'm stuck.

In this case, I want to use the package xgboost.

I have brew installed, after launching a terminal using Rosetta:

%brew install xgboost
Warning: xgboost 1.3.3 is already installed and up-to-date.

It appears installed OK here:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/xgboost

I also have Python installed here:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9

But no matter how I configure an Interpreter in Pycharm, I can't seem to get the package recognised.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am very unsure exactly how, but I've got this working.

Following: https://abbasegbeyemi.me/blog/homebrew-python-apple-m1

I changed the order of elements in my path:
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin

then a new interpreter in Pycharm using:
usr/local/Cellar/Python@3.9/3.9.2_2/bin/python3.9

Now I can install packages just using pip in pycharm and it works.

This has been 6 hours of pain - warning to anyone who isn't well versed in macs, setting up an M1 for python dev was a complete nightmare for me.

Answer (score 0):

Docs: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html
Pre-built binary wheel for Python

If you are planning to use Python, consider installing XGBoost from a pre-built binary wheel, available from Python Package Index (PyPI). You may download and install it by running

```
# Ensure that you are downloading one of the following:
#   * xgboost-{version}-py2.py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
#   * xgboost-{version}-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl
pip3 install xgboost
```

Comment: thanks, but I've tried this of course - it gives error:
Building wheel for xgboost (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'i....